# Google EMM API troubles

Tags: android, android-for-work

Good day! 
I have interest in Google Play EMM

I have created Device Policy Controller and created Work Profile.
Created  a Google Developers Console project and added EMM API.
Created master service account.
In master service account I obtained EMM token.

I have downloaded Google Play EMM API Client Library for Java.
As I know, I just need to call something like

```
Enterprise enterprise = new Enterprise();
enterprise.setPrimaryDomain(primaryDomainName);
Enterprise result = androidEnterprise.enterprises()
   .enroll(authenticationToken, enterprise).execute();

EnterpriseAccount enterpriseAccount = new EnterpriseAccount();
enterpriseAccount.setAccountEmail(serviceAccountEmail);
androidEnterprise.enterprises().setAccount(result.getId(),
enterpriseAccount).execute();
```

First question - how do I add device(android phone) to master service account grammatically?
If i was using Google Android for Work and Google system by default - i would use "Device Enrollment" application. But I have no idea how to do this in programming way.

Second one - in the sample there are such lines

```
// Optional: you might want to store the bound enterprise's info, but
// these details can always be retrieved with an Enterprises.List call.
```

Where do they store ?
At Google servers? Am I right when I think that when I do 
enterprise.setPrimaryDomain(primaryDomainName);
I get access to all enrolled customers?

Third - is there any NORMAL samples ? Or step by step howto? There is not a lot of information about all this after all (
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still You have same issue? Please let me know i think i can help you for enroll.

Change request like this:

```
Enterprise enterprise = new Enterprise();
enterprise.setPrimaryDomain(primaryDomainName);
enterprise.setId("Unique_EMM_ID"); //Which you will get from Google in mail
enterprise.setKind("androidenterprise#enterprise");

try{

      AndroidEnterprise.Enterprises.Enroll enroll = androidEnterprise.enterprises().enroll(authenticationToken, enterprise);
      enroll.setToken(token);

      Enterprise result = enroll.execute();

      EnterpriseAccount enterpriseAccount = new EnterpriseAccount();
      enterpriseAccount.setKind("androidenterprise#enterpriseAccount");
      enterpriseAccount.setAccountEmail(serviceAccountEmail);

      androidEnterprise.enterprises().setAccount(result.getId(), enterpriseAccount).execute();

   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Try like this.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: where do I get "token" from  enroll.setToken(token); ?

Comment: enroll.execute(); is no more . execute method is missing

Answer (score 0):

Answer for First question:

You can add device to MSA from https://admin.google.com/
1. Go to admin link
2. Add some user in Users tab. For Example - yourname@yourdomain.com
3. Download Devices Policy from Google Play Store.
4. add your user email id then create profile. 
5. that way you can add your user to admin means MSA.

I hope this will help you.
Even you can add scope for your project from admin. let me know if you want more information about it.